# Truncating double numbers

Tags: java, numbers, rounding, number-formatting

I'm working with a java program that computes for the Earliest Deadline Algorithm. Everything seems to work fine except for the double numbers. When I compute for the Averages (Turnaround time and Waiting time), normally the answer would be something like this:

```
18.566666666666663
```

I want to CUT (not round off) the answer to two decimal places so the answer should be:

```
18.56
```

Okay, so I tried printing the results on the console screen:

```
System.out.println (String.format ("%.2f", ttAve)); // ttAve contains 18.566666666666663
```

But then, the numbers will be rounded off when printed:

```
18.57
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hint: start by multiplying your answer by 100.  FYI: the usual term for what you want is "truncate".

Comment: Or convert the large number to a string and then format.

Comment: Here's what I did: I convert the whole double number into string times 100. Then I tried splitting the string with the delimiter dot. I parsed the string back to double but the string doesn't seem to split. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(18.566666666666663));
```

Note that both `System.out.printf` and `DecimalFormat` use system-default locale for formatting, so you may see unexpectedly `18,56` instead of `18.56` in some countries. If this is undesired, you can specify the locale explicitly:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##", 
                                     DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(18.566666666666663));
```

Comment: Thank you for this one! It solved my problem! Just a quick note for those who will stumble upon the same problem: DecimalFormat is from java.text package; Locale is from java.util package; and RoundingMode is from java.math package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
double cutValue = Math.floor(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Comment: For `-18.5666` this approach would produce `-18.57`. I don't know whether OP cares about negative numbers though.

Comment: Tagir was right. But there are rare chance that the user might input a negative integer. But better safe than sorry. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code?

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println (format.format(ttAve));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
float roundResult (float f) {
   int precise = 100;
   f = f * precise;
   int i = (int) f;
   return (float) i / precise;
}
```